# Limit POST access on REST API (authentication)

Tags: parse-platform

I'm very new to Parse and I've just setup a `parse-server` and a `parse-dashboard`

I would like to limit access of the REST API (when I call a POST for a url such as http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/posts) only to some users.

To do this I've setup a Role with Administrator name and added to this an User

I've created the ACL With:

```
var posts = new Parse.Object("posts");
var postsACL = new Parse.ACL();

postsACL.setRoleWriteAccess("Administrator", true);

posts.setACL(posts);

posts.save();
```

After this, I've run another script to add one User to this role:

```
Parse.User.logIn("username", "password", {
  success: function(user) {
    console.log('User logged in');
    var role = new Parse.Role("Administrator", new Parse.ACL());
    role.getUsers().add(user);

    role.save();

    console.log('Role saved');
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    console.log('Login failed');
  }
});
```

If I check on the Parse Dashboard I see one Role called Administrator and if I click on users I see my user.

But when I try to make a post (with `Postman`) I am able to insert on posts collection without authenticating.

Can someone help me?

Comment: http://blog.parse.com/learn/secure-your-app-one-class-at-a-time/    docs should have what u want for restriction on class access

Answer (score 0):

The acl you set is only work for that object. I think Class Level Permission is what you want. http://blog.parse.com/learn/secure-your-app-one-class-at-a-time/

BTW,  It is possible to modify these permissions without the dashboard.  https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-Server/wiki/Compatibility-with-Hosted-Parse#class-level-permissions

Comment: Yes! Yesterday after a lot of search i've realized that my ACL was related to a single Row and not at class level. I've so changed this to CLP but now i'm not able to perform REST API call. I set Basic authentication but i even get error 119 - Unauthorized...

Comment: Your header of the request should contains X-Parse-Session-Token, which is your admin user's token. You can get it after login(sessionToken or something like that). 

curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appId" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: key" \
  -H "X-Parse-Session-Token: tokenOfAdminUser" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Test

Comment: Mhhh... so i cant use Postman for example to make this call (i've used the API Client and i've look this X-Parse-Session-Token). So, now i need a way to make this call via Java (because i have to write a java program that will perform POST). I will try to make a simple LOGIN invoking login endpoint and after that, make the call. Parse dont' have Java API

Comment: Parse have Android SDK, and API docs. https://parse.com/docs/android_guide
Requests via sdk are with the currentUser's token.

Comment: So i can use Android SKD in a "simple java project"? Yest, Android are written in java, i will need just some functionality (post object with auth user, CLP and ACL). I try now to setup a Java project with that SDK

Comment: Sorry I have not notice that you say "Java". Maybe you can use this one https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j